# Elsevier cas-sc template: figure caption cannot be centered

Tags: captions, justification, els-cas

I am using Elsevier's  `cas-sc.cls`. Captions of figures are left-aligned, but I want the captions to be aligned to the center below the figure. I tried using `\captionsetup{justification=centering}` along with the package `\usepackage{caption}`, but that doesn't seem to work. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[pos=htbp]
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{My caption.}
\label{FIG}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Please help.

Comment: Being `cas-sc` a documentclass for journal papers, you're supposed to stick with the template. Changing the format will not make the editor happy, I guess.
Unless you are using it for other purposes, of course

Comment: Welcome to TeX - LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class provides a `align` option to the `figure` and `table` environments which sets the alignment of *both* the contents of the figure/table and the position of the caption. That doesn't work, however, because the caption is typeset in a `\parbox` with the width equal to the value of the `width` option, and inside the `\parbox` the text is justified by default. The correct way would be to put the alignment *inside* the `\parbox`.

There are three (hacky) ways to have what you want. The first (and slightly less hacky) is to use `align=\centering` to center the `\parbox` that contains the caption and use `width=<width-of-the-typeset-caption>` to make the width of the `\parbox` just right. It requires a bunch of manual tweaking to get the value of `width` right. `3cm` seems to be a good guess for your example:

```latex
\begin{figure}[pos=htbp,width=3cm,align=\centering]
```

The second way (hacky, and depends on an implementation detail of `els-cas`), is to use the pseudo-hook of `align` to redefine `\@parboxrestore` to inject `\centering` if used inside a `cas-sc` caption. To do that you define:

```latex
\makeatletter
\def\redefparbox{\def\@parboxrestore{\@arrayparboxrestore\let\\\@normalcr
  \if@minipage\expandafter\@gobbletwo\fi
  \@firstofone{\centering\casscparboxtest}}}
\def\casscparboxtest#1{%
  \ifx\rightskip#1\relax\expandafter\dimen@\else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi\@gobble{#1}}
\makeatother
```

and then use:

```latex
\begin{figure}[pos=htbp,align=\redefparbox]
```

The third way (also hacky, also depends on the implementation, and is politically incorrect), is to just redefine `\__make_fig_caption:nn` to put the `align` at the right place:

```latex
% -----------
% Definition for the third way:
\ExplSyntaxOn
% For `figure`:
\cs_gset_protected:Npn \__make_fig_caption:nn #1#2
  {
    \skip_vertical:N \l_fig_abovecap_skip
    \parbox { \dim_eval:n { \l_fig_width_dim } }
     {
       \tl_use:N \l_fig_align_tl
       \sffamily \small \textbf{\color{scolor}#1:}~#2\par
    }
    \skip_vertical:N \l_fig_belowcap_skip
  }
% For `table`:
\cs_gset_protected:Npn \__make_tbl_caption:nn #1#2
  {
    \skip_vertical:N \l_tbl_abovecap_skip
    \parbox{ \dim_eval:n { \l_tbl_width_dim } }
      {
        \tl_use:N \l_tbl_align_tl
         \sffamily \small \textbf{\color{scolor}#1}\par#2\par\vskip4pt
      }
    \skip_vertical:N \l_tbl_belowcap_skip
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
% -----------
```

---

Here's an MWE with the three options marked:

```latex
 \documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% -----------
% Definition for the second way:
\makeatletter
\def\redefparbox{\def\@parboxrestore{\@arrayparboxrestore\let\\\@normalcr
  \if@minipage\expandafter\@gobbletwo\fi
  \@firstofone{\centering\casscparboxtest}}}
\def\casscparboxtest#1{%
  \ifx\rightskip#1\relax\expandafter\dimen@\else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi\@gobble{#1}}
\makeatother
% -----------

% -----------
% Definition for the third way:
\ExplSyntaxOn
% For `figure`:
\cs_gset_protected:Npn \__make_fig_caption:nn #1#2
  {
    \skip_vertical:N \l_fig_abovecap_skip
    \parbox { \dim_eval:n { \l_fig_width_dim } }
     {
       \tl_use:N \l_fig_align_tl
       \sffamily \small \textbf{\color{scolor}#1:}~#2\par
    }
    \skip_vertical:N \l_fig_belowcap_skip
  }
% For `table`:
\cs_gset_protected:Npn \__make_tbl_caption:nn #1#2
  {
    \skip_vertical:N \l_tbl_abovecap_skip
    \parbox{ \dim_eval:n { \l_tbl_width_dim } }
      {
        \tl_use:N \l_tbl_align_tl
         \sffamily \small \textbf{\color{scolor}#1}\par#2\par\vskip4pt
      }
    \skip_vertical:N \l_tbl_belowcap_skip
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
% -----------

\begin{document}

% \begin{figure}[pos=htbp,width=3cm,align=\centering] % First way
% \begin{figure}[pos=htbp,align=\redefparbox] % Second way
\begin{figure}[pos=htbp,align=\centering] % Third way
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{My caption.}
\label{FIG}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```